# How to Pass size to array for two dimensional Array in Swift

Tags: java, swift, xcode, arraylist

Here Span is custom Class.

ArrayList[] tempArray = new ArrayList[count];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java code is creating an array of length `count`, of `ArrayList<Span>` - it is an array of `ArrayList<Span>`s.

Since there are no separate types for `ArrayList` and `Array` in Swift, you can just use arrays for both of them. The type overall is a `[[Span]]`.

```
var tempArray = Array(repeating: [Span](), count: count)
```

`tempArray` will have `count` elements, each one is an empty array of `Span`s, into which you can add more `Span`s.

Note that translating code is quite like translating a spoken language. Translating a spoken language word-by-word usually results in very unnatural sounding text. Similarly, translating code line by line usually doesn't give you good-looking Swift code. You should get a high-level understanding of what the code is doing, and, in your own "words", write the code that does the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate and reserve capacity of an array in swift as follows.

```
var tempArray: [Span] = []
tempArray.reserveCapacity(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// you can init it like this.
var array = Array<Span>()

// or use init it samply like this
// var array:[Span] =  []
let tmp = span.init()
// you can add element by this method
array.append(tmp)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to use just `var tempArray = [Span]`